# Issue with CURLOPT_CAPATH in libcurl

Tags: openssl, libcurl

I am using CURLOPT_CAPATH to set the path for directory holding CA certificates

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlobj->curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/var/certs")
```

But it does not seem to work. It fails to choose the certificate.

```
* About to connect() to xxxxxxxxxxxxx port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.x.x.x...
* Adding handle: conn: 0xf49120d8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xf49120d8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxxx (10.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /var/certs
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection 0
```

It works if I explicitly specify the certificate

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlobj->curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/var/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
```

```
* About to connect() to xxxxxxxxxxxxx port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.x.x.x...
* Adding handle: conn: 0xf501a4c8
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xf501a4c8) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxxx  (10.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /var/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
```

As mentioned in man page

> If libcurl is built against OpenSSL, the certificate directory must be
> prepared using the OpenSSL c_rehash utility.

I have prepared the certificate directory using c_rehash, but still it is not working.

```
root@test:/#
root@test:/# c_rehash /var/certs/
Doing /var/certs/
root@test:/#
root@test:/# ls /var/certs/
ca-certificates.crt
root@test:/#
```

FYI
Curl version: 7.33.0, ssl version: OpenSSL/1.0.1u

Comment: What are the contents of `/var/certs`?

Comment: What OS/distro/version? That looks like `c_rehash` did nothing.  Perhaps rerun it with the `-v` option, or as `openssl rehash /var/certs`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Its a customized linux. Both of them did not help. However if I rename the ```.crt``` to ```.pem``` c_rehash seems to create ```3e45d192.0``` file but that also did not help

Comment: Was your curl install built to use OpenSSL?  If so, your `libcurl.so` file should have dependencies on both `libssl.so` and `libcrypto.so`.  (Curl can be built to use OpenSSL, GnuTLS, or wolfSSL.)

Comment: Yes. It is built to use OpenSSL. ```# ldd /lib/libcurl.so.4 | grep ssl
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf7730000)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251734/discussion-between-karthick-and-andrew-henle).